# Why is initial commit not shown in change log

Tags: javers

I'm wondering why the initial commit of a new object is not visible list of changes?

When I have for example:

```
MyObject secondo = new MyObject(2);
javers.commit("Me",secondo);

List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(
    QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(2, MyObject.class).build());
String changeLog = javers.processChangeList(changes, new MyTextChangeLog());

System.out.println(changeLog);
```

I see the following INFO line on the console:

```
2017-04-05 13:11:04.896  INFO 7425 --- [           main] org.javers.core.Javers                   : Commit(id:1.0, snapshots:1, author:Me, changes - NewObject:1), done in 97 millis (factory:97, persist:0)
```

However the changeLog print is empty! Why?

Regards,
Gerard

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried NewObject changes filter?
http://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#new-object-filter